# using linked lists to determine subsets

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to determine if a list (P) is a proper subset of another list (Q). These are sorted in ascending order.

Considering a few cases such as P={2,3} and Q={2,3,5} and P={2,4} and Q={1,2,3,4} I'm trying t develop my algorithm..

Thus far I know that I will be traversing through the linked list while p!=nullptr, and I know that if p->value==q->value that I will move to the next node.

But after that I'm kinda stuck..I think p->value > q->value might also be a condition as well..

Can you provide me with any hints moving forward?

Comment: Do you actually need to implement this as part of some exercise, or can you use [`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes)?

Comment: @user904963, Oops, I didn't see the proper part. Without that, it's never 100% clear whether the OP means the actual definition or a slightly different one.

Answer (score 0):

If p-value > q-value no to next element in q (p current element stay in the same place)